# Implementing functionality/code directly in database system

Tags: database

RDBMS packages today offer a tremendous amount of functionality beyond standard data storage and retrieval.  SQL Server for example can send emails, expose web service methods, and execute CLR code amongst other capabilities.  However, I have always tried to limit the amount of processing my database server does to just data storage and retrieval as much as possible, for the following reasons:

- A database server is harder to scale than web servers
- In a lot of projects I've worked on, the DB server is a lot busier than the web servers, and thus has less spare capacity
- It potentially exposes your database server to a security attack (web services for example)

My question is, how do you decide how much functionality or code should be implemented directly on your database server versus other servers in your architecture?  What recommendations do you have for people starting new projects?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031/database-triggers

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118955/architecture-for-a-business-objects-database-access-layer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know Microsoft SQL Server and Oracle really push using stored procedures for everything, which helps to encapsulate the relational architecture and creates a more procedural interface for the software developers, who typically aren't as facile writing SQL queries.

But then half your application logic is written in PL/SQL (or T-SQL or whatever) and the other half is written in your application language, Java or PHP or C#, etc.  The DBA is typically responsible for coding the procedures, and the developers are responsible for everything else.  No one has visibility and access to the full application logic.  This tends to slow down development, testing, and future revisions to the project.

Also software development tools tend to be poor for stored procedures.  Tools and best practices for debugging, source control, and testing all seem to be about 10-15 years behind the state of the art for application languages.

So I tend to stay away from stored procedures and triggers if at all possible.  Except in certain cases when a well-placed stored procedure can make a complex SQL operation happen entirely in the server instead of shuffling data back and forth.  This can be very effective at eliminating performance bottlenecks.

It's possible to go too far in the other direction as well.  People who prefer the application manage data versus metadata, and employ designs like Entity-Attribute-Value or Polymorphic Associations, get themselves into trouble.  Let the database manage that.  Use referential integrity constraints (foreign keys).  Use transactions.

Answer (score 0):

The vendors have one set of best practices.  You, however, voice concerns with that.

Years ago I supported a **Major Software Product**. Major.

They said "The database is relational storage.  Nothing more."  Every user conference people would ask about stored procedure, triggers, and all that malarkey.

Their architect was firm.  As soon as you get away from plain-old-SQL, you've got a support and maintenance nightmare.  They did object-relational mapping from the DB into their product, and everything else was in their product.

This scales well.  Multiple application servers can easily share a single database server.